# Product filter shows incorrect result admin product grid magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.3 
 I have added a custom column `simple_count` to count the total no of products in a configurable product.and created a custom attribute `simple_count` in admin. Filter is working fine if i use `'type'  => 'text'` but when i use `'type'  => 'number'`, then filter shows incorrect result.
Please see the code below:

```
$this->addColumn('simple_count', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Simple Count'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width' => '100px',
          'type'  => 'number',           
          'index'     => 'simple_count',
          'renderer' => 'Wcl_Employee_Block_Adminhtml_Employee_Renderer_Simplecount',         
      ));
```

For rendering section:

```
class Wcl_Employee_Block_Adminhtml_Employee_Renderer_Simplecount extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
            $entityId = $row['entity_id'];
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entityId);
                $productType = $product->getTypeID(); 
                $sum = 0;
                if($productType == 'configurable'):     
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
                        //echo "Simple Count:".count($childProducts);
                        //$sum =0;
                        foreach($childProducts as $itempro):
                        $productdata = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($itempro->getId());
                        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productdata)->getQty();
                        $sum = $sum + $stock;
                        endforeach;
                        $product->setSimpleCount($sum); $product->save();
                        if($sum == 0):
                          return '0';
                        else:
                return $sum;
                        endif;
                else:
                        $product->setSimpleCount($sum); $product->save();   
                        return '0';     
                endif;   
   }     
}
```

If anyone knows this, please gelp me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can use filter_condition_callback like this 
    $this->addColumn('simple_count', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Simple Count'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width' => '100px',
              'type'  => 'number',           
              'index'     => 'simple_count',
              'renderer' =>      'Wcl_Employee_Block_Adminhtml_Employee_Renderer_Simplecount', 
              'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterValidityCondition'),            
          ));

    protected function _filterValidityCondition($collection, $column) {
            if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return;
            }
            if (isset($value['from']) && $value['from']) {

$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($column->getIndex(), array('gteq' => $from));
            }
            if (isset($value['to']) && $value['to']) {

$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($column->getIndex(), array('leeq' => $to));
            }
        }
```

Comment: No,still the problem exist, when i take from 20 to 30, then also it shows other results.

Comment: anyone have any idea then please suggest the problem

Comment: when i filter data using type number, it shows incorrect result